# What does this variable R mean

Tags: private-key, blockchain.info, ecdsa

What does this variable R mean if it is the same in transaction signatures, and can I find S Z from the transaction I want an explanation or someone helps me to find the variables

type address:  3AQYerxq4C2qmjthFpKCHYuoM8mzMRE9Q7
ADDRESS-R-SCAN:
Data for pubkey: 3AQYerxq4C2qmjthFpKCHYuoM8mzMRE9Q7 has   50  Txs
Fetching Txs from offset        0
Fetching Txs from offset        50
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:
87c735eb8413a42fc856eec1ff432ef43c25
Resued R-Value:

Resued R-Value:

Address 3AQYerxq4C2qmjthFpKCHYuoM8mzMRE9Q7 has 15 reused R values!

Comment: Are you asking us "how to extract the private key of the address containing $18000 worth of bitcoins"?

Comment: I don't want the private key, I just want to know what this variable is and how I can extract other variables

Answer (score 0):

ECDSA signing uses a random number called the *nonce*. A signature contains two numbers (r, S). r is generated only from the nonce and the nonce mustn't be reused. When the nonce is reused, r is the same too.

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/5/5767.html Eq 2 shows how r only depends on the S.

I don't know what you're referring to as Z.

Comment: Because I am currently collapsed and I want a solution. I lost my wallet in 2014 and I could not reach it. There are approximately 9 Bitcoins in it. I am looking for it and I could not reach it. I thought about committing suicide.

Comment: What is the solution? Please, your watch, my wallet, and you extract the variables so that I can access the private key

Comment: Which wallet software was it? File recovery tools might be useful.

Comment: The problem is that my device is being destroyed because of the bombing, because I live in Yemen and there is war

Comment: The war completely destroyed my house, and my transformer was inside it

Comment: Is the address that has reused R values your address? The address didn't exist in 2014, but if your address has reused R values it should be possible to recover.

Comment: No, you did not understand me, I did not lose it in 2014, I mean the war started in 2014, but I lost the wallet last year and my house was bombed at the end of last year in about 9 months. I ask you to excuse me because I do the translation through Google and the translation is not accurate because I do not understand English well

Comment: this is my address 1XCPdWb6kk7PGfvbdRbRuNh51aPc4vqC7

Comment: I have scanned the first 10 thousand transactions. I couldn't find any duplicate r values. Unfortunately it seems that it's not possible to recover the coins but I'll report to you once again once I have scanned all transactions

Comment: Thank you very much for your understanding of the difficult situation that he and I and colleagues passed through because of the war. There are many people who lost their money saved in Bitcoin in particular in Yemen, and this is bad luck

Comment: @hishamyem I have scanned all the transactions. Recovering doesn't seem to be possible. Sorry for your loss.